# Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface query with new query()

Tags: coldfusion

```
Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface query.
Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists.


The error occurred in D:/sites/xxxxx/mobile/resource/nodeRO.cfc: line 34
32 :    this.touch = 0;
33 : 
34 :    **variables.QueryService = new query();**
35 :    variables.QueryService.setName("qryResult");
```

I have checked mappings. 
Non new query powered objects are OK
Restarted CF service and it didn't help

Using CF 9.02

Now what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hunting around all over the place, it turned out that the CF server had been updated/upgraded to an new directory. The old CF root directory was renamed.

There is a custom mapping that has to exist for `new query()` and others to work. Since that mapping was missing, it could not find `query.cfc`.